# Import .stories file into another .stories file with Storybook?

Tags: storybook

Can you import one .stories file into another .stories with Storybook?

Eg I have

```
/component1/component1.tsx
/component1/component1.stories.tsx
/component2/component2.tsx
/component2/component2.stories.tsx
```

I would like to also have a story for all of my components:

In `/all-components/all-components.stories.tsx`

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Component1Story from '../component1/component1.stories.tsx';
import Component2Story from '../component2/component2.stories.tsx';

export const Test = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Component1Story />
      <Component2Story />
    </div>
  );
};

export default {
  title: 'Components',
};
```

I get this error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

> Check the render method of `storyFn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should be doable as your stories are just React components. Your problem is happening because you're trying to import the **default** from your module, which is actually just an object:

```js
export default {
  title: 'Components',
};
```

All stories are named exports, and you should import them with destructuring:

```js
import { Component1Story } from '../component1/component1.stories';
import { Component2Story } from '../component2/component2.stories';
```

I created an example for you which shows a working scenario [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-shannon-d0p34?file=/src/stories/0-Welcome.stories.tsx).

p.s. It's interesting to know that starting with Storybook 6 there's a new mechanism to simplify the creation and reuse of stories so stay tuned! It's called [Args](https://github.com/storybookjs/storybook/blob/next/docs/src/pages/formats/component-story-format/index.md#args-story-inputs).

Comment: Doesn't appear to work any more. `JSX element type 'AnyImportedStory' does not have any construct or call signatures.`

Answer (score 0):

I've found approach that appears to work for me, however I've only just started using Storybook so cant really say whether or not this approach is recommended etc.

Define your isolated stories:

```js
// /component1/component1.stories.tsx
export const Component1Story: StoryObj<typeof Component1> = {};
```

```js
// /component2/component2.stories.tsx
export const Component2Story: StoryObj<typeof Component2> = {};
```

Import them into your master story, and re-export them:

```js
// /all-components/all-components.stories.tsx
import * as Component1Stories from '../component1/component1.stories';
import * as Component2Stories from '../component2/component2.stories';

export const Component1Story = Component1Stories.Component1Story;
export const Component2Story = Component2Stories.Component2Story;
```